# iOS Calendar's join button for video conferencing URLs

Tags: ios, swift

I noticed that the iOS calendar understands URL's of video conferencing app meetings (e.g. Webex, Zoom, Microsoft Teams, Google Meet etc.). Even when I have the app not installed on the iPhone, it knows from the URL that this is a videoconferencing app meeting link, so it show a section with the URL and a 'Join' button. If the app is installed, it shows the app icon (e.g. Webex), otherwise it shows a video icon.

I'm not sure if this is some capability of Universal links on iOS, but I have not found anything related to that in the documentation.

The calendar event was created outside of any of these apps and was simply a copy-paste of the meeting URL in the calendar event (created using Outlook), so nothing was done within the videoconferencing app to associate it with the calendar event. iOS Calendar seems to understand this from the meeting URL

Does anyone know how to achieve this effect of making the iOS calendar show a 'Join' button next to meeting URL?